# SharePoint online - Get all those users given permissions but left organisation

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad

Is there any way to get all users giving the permissions from all sites/lists of SharePoint online who no more exists in AzureAD . They may be left the organization but they still exists in SharePoint groups or assigned permissions directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Retrieve all users from the user information list of the site collection.
2. Check whether those users are valid or invalid in the Active Directory.

Reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-get-all-orphan-users-present-in-sharepoint-onpremise-site

Below is the C# CSOM code

```
using System;  
using System.Net;  
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;  
namespace OrphanUser {  
    class Program {  
        static void Main(string[] args) {  
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://portal/sites/site1");  
            NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("userName", "passWord");  
            ctx.Credentials = cred;  
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();  
            Web web = ctx.Web;  
            ListItemCollection itemColl = null;  
            User user = null;  
            bool isGroup = false;  
            string userName = string.Empty;  
            string status = string.Empty;  
            itemColl = web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems(new CamlQuery());  
            ctx.Load(itemColl, items => items.Include(item => item.FieldValuesAsText, item => item.Id, item => item.DisplayName));  
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();  
            foreach(ListItem itm in itemColl) {  
                user = web.EnsureUser(itm.DisplayName);  
                try {  
                    ctx.Load(user, u => u.LoginName);  
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();  
                    isGroup = false;  
                } catch {  
                    isGroup = true;  
                }  
                if (!isGroup) {  
                    userName = itm.DisplayName;  
                    if (userName.ToLower() == "NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users".ToLower() || userName.ToLower() == "Helpdesk Administrator".ToLower() || userName.ToLower() == "Everyone except external users".ToLower() || userName.ToLower() == "SharePoint\\SYSTEM".ToLower() || userName.ToLower() == "Everyone".ToLower() || userName.ToLower().StartsWith("nt authority\\") || userName.ToLower() == "SharePoint App".ToLower() || userName.ToLower() == "System Account".ToLower() || userName.ToLower().Contains("_spo")) {  
                        continue;  
                    } else {  
                        GetOrphanedUsers(ctx, web, itm.DisplayName);  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        public static void GetOrphanedUsers(ClientContext ctx, Web web, string userValue) {  
            try {  
                Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ClientPickerQuery.ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters query = new Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ClientPickerQuery.ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters();  
                query.AllowEmailAddresses = false;  
                query.AllowMultipleEntities = false;  
                query.ForceClaims = false;  
                query.MaximumEntitySuggestions = 50;  
                query.PrincipalType = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.All;  
                query.PrincipalSource = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalSource.All;  
                query.QueryString = userValue;  
                query.AllUrlZones = false;  
                query.SharePointGroupID = 0;  
                query.WebApplicationID = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");  
                ClientResult < String > resultInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ClientPickerQuery.ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.ClientPeoplePickerSearchUser(ctx, query);  
                try {  
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();  
                } catch {}  
                if (resultInfo == null || resultInfo.Value == null || resultInfo.Value == "[]") {  
                    Console.WriteLine(userValue + " is an Orphan user");  
                }  
            } catch {}  
        }  
    }  
}
```